# Arabic doesn't show properly in SQLite after conversion from MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, arabic-support

I have a huge MySQL database. it's full of Arabic text, one of the tables' info can be shown here:

[image]

I used [this program](http://sqlite2009pro.azurewebsites.net/) to convert it to an SQLite db file, however, after conversion, the letters appear in messed up way:

[image]

Also, I tried to view the exported file using 'SQLite Database Browser', and it was the same messed up behavior. needles to say it was the same in Android.

Comment: is the arabic text in utf8 format? after damping the data, could you open the file with editor and see it in arabic? (try to dump small amount of data or small table in order to check it with text editor)

Comment: No, Notepade++ shows weird characters too, and I used 'Encode in UTF-8' option,
but, in the app that I used to convert the database, it shows the valid text in read only mode. however in edit mode it does what in the picture above.

Comment: Apparently, that "Pro Enterprise Manager" is buggy, or the MySQL database is not labelled with the correct encoding.

Comment: so maybe you entered the text with other encoding, it could be that it old data that entered with non-utf8 encoding which you convert with another program. can you choose encoding for exporting data?

Comment: I added all the data in UTF-8 encoding using some MySQL GUI Client,as I exported them from a UTF-8 encoded csv file, and Notepad++ can read the .sql file properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to a conclusion, [the program I used](http://sqlite2009pro.azurewebsites.net/) wasn't good at handling Arabic, so instead,

• I exported each table as a CSV file using [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/).

• Then I created a new SQLite3 database using [DB Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/).

• Then I re-imported the new CSV files as tables, and Arabic was imported Successfully.

needless to say, in each of these steps I made sure to always use UTF-8 encoding in importing/exporting.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line in the top of your SQL file:

```
PRAGMA encoding="UTF-8";
```